# SUM and GROUP BY in SQL totaling issue

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I am working with two different covid datasets which include reported data from all countries. The issue I am having is with the `sum` and `group by` functions, where SQL is summing all grouped rows which unnecessarily increases the output. With the example below, the total deaths should be *4,849* with *17,441* total cases.

*Note: The datasets included the city/province for each country, and the below is already grouped by country

```
CREATE TABLE covid.deaths(
    country varchar(255),
    deaths int
);


CREATE TABLE covid.confirmed_cases(
    country varchar(255),
    cases int
);
```

```
    *country*   *deaths*    *cases*
    China   0   747
    China   0   519
    China   0   1500
    China   0   264
    China   1   159
    China   3   1992
    China   2   1008
    China   4   1632
    China   7   1650
    China   6   190
    China   213 1260
    China   8   1197
    China   58  3260
    China   13  362
    China   22  703
    China   4512 998
```

However when I run the query below I get *279,056* total cases and *77,584* deaths. In trying to self-solve this issue, I removed one of the `sum` functions (but kept the date) and found that with the output, SQL is populating the total down the column for all rows and then summing those columns when both `sum` functions are present (essentially the equation SQL is using is `total deaths or cases x number of rows`).

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(d.country_region, "Unknown") AS country,
    SUM(d._11_16_21) as deaths,
    SUM(c._11_16_21) as cases
FROM `covid.deaths` as d
JOIN `covid.confirmed_cases` as c
    ON d.country_region = c.country_region
WHERE d.country_region = "China"
GROUP BY 
    d.country_region
```

**Output with the cases `sum` function removed**

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(d.country_region, "Unknown") AS country,
    SUM(d._11_16_21) as deaths,
    c._11_16_21 as cases
FROM `covid.deaths` as d
JOIN `covid.confirmed_cases` as c
    ON d.country_region = c.country_region
WHERE d.country_region = "China"
GROUP BY 
    d.country_region, c._11_16_21  


    *country*   *deaths*    *cases*
    China   4849    747
    China   4849    519
    China   4849    1500
    China   4849    264
    China   4849    159
    China   4849    1992
    China   4849    1008
    China   4849    1632
    China   4849    1650
    China   4849    190
    China   4849    1260
    China   4849    1197
    China   4849    3260
    China   4849    362
    China   4849    703
    China   4849    998
```

Is there a way to have SQL only show the unique sum as the output?

*Note: Coalesce is being used as there are some country names which are `null`

Comment: Please update your question to show the create statements for the tables

Comment: Your query references columns country_region, country, and _11_16_21 which are not in your sample data. Please clarify your question by providing the actual source data. Based on the results it appears your source tables have more than one row per country_region. This problem can be solved by either using subqueries to pre-aggregate each table separately, or adding more fields to your join criteria so each row in the confirmed_cases table matches with only one row the in the deaths table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum them separately before joining covid cases to deaths

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(d.country_region, c.country_region, 'Unknown') AS country,
    d.deaths,
    c.cases
FROM (
    SELECT country_region
    , SUM(`_11_16_21`) as deaths
    FROM `covid.deaths` 
    WHERE country_region = 'China'
    GROUP BY country_region
) as d
JOIN (
    SELECT country_region
    , SUM(`_11_16_21`) as cases
    FROM  `covid.confirmed_cases`
    WHERE country_region = 'China'
    GROUP BY country_region
) as c
  ON c.country_region = d.country_region
```

Comment: Note that I changed the FULL JOIN to normal INNER JOIN.  Because I'm guessing this is for a MySql or MariaDB.  So there's a fair chance FULL JOIN isn't supported on your database.

Comment: The inner join works as long as all country_regions have reported cases and deaths. If rows are missing from either set, results will be under reported.

Comment: Ok, but just be aware that something like `FULL OUTER JOIN` exists in most RDBMS. But the alternative is just ugly (a union between a left join & right join query)